# D3js Line chart configuration

Tags: d3.js

Someone knows why the line is not shown in the graph?

```
 var dataline = [
        {"mes": 1, "impuestoPorcentaje": 30},
        {"mes": 2, "impuestoPorcentaje": 49},
        {"mes": 3, "impuestoPorcentaje": 100},
        {"mes": 4, "impuestoPorcentaje": 20},
        {"mes": 5, "impuestoPorcentaje": 200},
        {"mes": 6, "impuestoPorcentaje": 150},
        {"mes": 7, "impuestoPorcentaje": 80},
        {"mes": 8, "impuestoPorcentaje": 170}
     ];

          var wl = 600;

          var hl = 450;

          var svgl = d3.select("body").append("svg")
             .attrs({
                width: wl,
                height: hl
             });



          var lineOne =  d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { 
                return d.mes * 33; 
              })
            .y(function(d) { 
                return h-(d.impuestoPorcentaje * 3);
              })
            .interpolate ("linear");



           var vis = svgl.append("path")
                .attrs({

                    d: lineOne(impuestoPorcentaje),
                    "stroke": "blue" ,
                    "stroke-width" : 2,
                    "fill" : "none"

                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *exactly* your code, there are 4 problems (actually 3, because I'm not sure about the first one):

1. Are you referencing "selection-multi"? Have in mind that "selection-multi" is not part of the default bundle. So, you have to put:

   ```
   <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. There is no `interpolate` in `d3.line`. It should be:

   ```
   .curve(d3.curveBasis);
   ```

   or whatever other curve you want.
3. You have to pass the data array to your line generator. So, instead of:

   ```
   d: lineOne(impuestoPorcentaje),
   ```

   it should be:

   ```
   d: lineOne(dataline),
   ```
4. There is no `h` in your code, but `hl`. So, in the line generator:

   ```
    .y(function(d) { 
        return hl-(d.impuestoPorcentaje * 3);
    })
   ```

This is your working code:

```js
 var dataline = [{
     "mes": 1,
     "impuestoPorcentaje": 30
 }, {
     "mes": 2,
     "impuestoPorcentaje": 49
 }, {
     "mes": 3,
     "impuestoPorcentaje": 100
 }, {
     "mes": 4,
     "impuestoPorcentaje": 20
 }, {
     "mes": 5,
     "impuestoPorcentaje": 200
 }, {
     "mes": 6,
     "impuestoPorcentaje": 150
 }, {
     "mes": 7,
     "impuestoPorcentaje": 80
 }, {
     "mes": 8,
     "impuestoPorcentaje": 170
 }];

 var wl = 600;

 var hl = 450;

 var svgl = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .attrs({
         width: wl,
         height: hl
     });



 var lineOne = d3.line()
     .x(function(d) {
         return d.mes * 33;
     })
     .y(function(d) {
         return hl - (d.impuestoPorcentaje * 3);
     })
     .curve(d3.curveBasis);



 var vis = svgl.append("path")
     .attrs({

         d: lineOne(dataline),
         "stroke": "blue",
         "stroke-width": 2,
         "fill": "none"

     });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't binding your data to your path.

```
svgl.append("path")
  .datum(dataline)
  .attrs({ /* ... */ });
```